# Django 3rd party packages not working

Tags: python, django, pip, package, python-imaging-library

Good day

I'm working through a Django projects book called Django by example

I am stuck working through the projects because I seem to be having trouble with 3rd party packages, namely taggit and pillow

Using pillow as an example..
This is the error I get when I makemigrations for my apps model:

```
(shop) PS C:\dan_projects\django_by_example_shop\myshop> py -3 .\manage.py makemigrations
SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:
ERRORS:
shop.Product.image: (fields.E210) Cannot use ImageField because Pillow is not installed.
HINT: Get Pillow at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow or run command "pip install Pillow".
```

Yet 'pip freeze' is telling me that pillow is installed:

```
(shop) PS C:\dan_projects\django_by_example_shop\myshop> pip freeze
Django==1.8.5
Pillow==2.9.0
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be running a different Python executable when you run manage.py, with your `py -3` command.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, simple using 'python' worked! Great name btw